# pySerial and reading binary data

Tags: pyserial

When the device I am communicating with sends binary data, I can recover most of it. However, there always seem to be some bytes missing, replaced by non-standard characters. For instance, one individual output looks like this:

```
\xc4\xa5\x06\x00.\xb3\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00=\xa9
```

The period and equals sign should be traditional bytes in hexadecimal format (I confirmed this in another application). Other times I get other weird characters such as ')' or 's'. These characters usually occur in the exact same spot (which varies with the command I passed to the device).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you displaying the output using something like this?:

```
print output
```

If some of your bytes happen to correspond with printable characters, they'll show up as characters.  Try this:

```
print output.encode('hex')
```

to see hex values for all your bytes.

Comment: Thanks. This is almost two years old, but it helped me out.

Comment: print ' '.join(map(lambda x:x.encode('hex'),output))  # this separates bytes with spaces

Answer (score 2):

At first I liked @RichieHindle answer, but when I tried it the hex bytes were all bunched together.
To get a friendlier output, I use

```
print ' '.join(map(lambda x:x.encode('hex'),output))
```

Comment: `print(' '.join(map(lambda x:x.encode('hex',s))))`
TypeError: map() requires at least two args
Never used lambdas, do you have an explanation?

Comment: In RichieHindle's answer, the hex encoding is done on all the bytes of the string "output", to produce one long hex number.   What my function does, is take the bytes individually from output and converts the hex, so I get the hex value of each byte, separated by spaces.  lambda is an easy way to make a simple (unnamed) function for map to apply to each element of the list in the second argument  to map.   Learn "map" and "lambda" and you'll never go back to your old way of doing things.  Trust me.

Comment: Years later, but if you found this answer and saw @chwi comment, the right-paren is misplaced in the comment.

Comment: So `print(' '.join(map(lambda x:x.encode('hex'), s)))` then :)