# How to read XBEE ZB data

Tags: python, hex, xbee

I have a python script which is listening for data from my XBEE S2 radios.  The data seems garbled.  It does not seem to be hex or anything else meaningful.

```
output:  {'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xae\x9c\xe6', 'rf_data':
'0\r\n\x00', 'source_addr': '\xe8f', 'id': 'rx', 'options': 'A'}
```

The above is what is received from all sending radios.  Of course with each radio it is a little different which indicates that each transmission is radio specific as it should be.

When I print 'rf_data' I get a 0 as I should or at least that is what I was looking for in this case.  But when I print 'source_addr' it is neither hex nor anything else at all.

First I want to understand what the data above means.  Next I want to output the source address to something meaningful. I have tried .decode("hex") but get the error that this is not a hex value.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

`rf_data` is a `0` followed by a carriage return, linefeed and null.  The sender is likely miscalculating the length of the data, since you wouldn't typically include the null-terminator of the sent string.

The source address is 8 bytes, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17241134/266392) does a good job of explaining how to do something with it:

> ```
> >>> value = '\x13\xa2\x00@y\xe6_'
>
> >>> pretty_value = ':'.join("{:02X}".format(ord(c)) for c in value)
> >>> print(pretty_value)
> 13:A2:00:40:79:E6:5F
> ```